# Issue with running KairosDb on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, kairosdb

I'm running KairosDb (time series db) on top of Cassandra. I'm experiencing a recurring debug message from Cassandra/Kairos that comes up all the time. They are able to connect to each other but I fear something is not correctly configured. Here is a snippet of the error and how its presented over and over in time:

```
08:06:00.000 [QuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] DEBUG 
[QuartzSchedulerThread.java:268] - batch acquisition of 0 triggers
08:06:00.000 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-3] DEBUG [JobRunShell.java:212] - 
Calling execute on job 
DEFAULT.org.kairosdb.core.reporting.MetricReporterService
08:06:00.001 [QuartzScheduler_Worker-3] DEBUG 
[MetricReporterService.java:93] - Reporting metrics
08:06:09.335 
[Hector.me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService-1] 
DEBUG [CassandraHostRetryService.java:123] - Retry service fired... nothing 
to do.
```

Has anyone experienced this before and knows the issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there are no problem with these messages, these are  perfectly normal.

KairosDB has some jobs triggered by Quartz that reports metrics, and when using Cassandra (Hector client) it checks for the hosts that have been marked down or are unresponsive.

Comment: Ok awesome, can you point me to any direction where I can read more about this?